# Content-Length undefined ? Weird error using Yahoo's PlaceSpotter sample php code

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I am currently using the following code:

```
<?php
/* Pre-requisite: Download the required PHP OAuth class from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php. This is used below */
require("OAuth.php");
$url = "https://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placespotter";
$cc_key = "MY_KEY";
$cc_secret = "MY_SECRET";
$text = "EYES ON LONDON Electric night in 100-meter dash";

$args = array();
$args["documentType"] = urlencode("text/plain");
$args["documentContent"] = urlencode($text);

$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"POST", $url,$args);
$request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array($request->to_header());//.',Content-Length: '.strlen($text));

//print_r($headers.',Content-Length: '.strlen($text));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// somehow this line is not solving the issue
// curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Length:'.strlen($text)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($rsp);
//echo "======= ENDING";
?>
```

With my own access keys and all, with the OAuth.php library.

Somehow I kept getting a Content-Length undefined error.

If I were to attempt to define Content-Length like this ( based on some answers seen here on StackOverFlow:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Length:'.strlen($text)));
```

I do not get any response.

May I know how can this issue be solved?

Thanks!

PS: the php example comes from the official example: https://gist.github.com/ydn/bcf8b301125c8ffa986f#file-placespotter-php

---

**LATEST EDIT**

I've updated my code based on @alexblex's comment

```
    <?php
/* Pre-requisite: Download the required PHP OAuth class from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php. This is used below */
require("OAuth.php");
$url = "https://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placespotter";
$cc_key = "MY_KEY";
$cc_secret = "MY_SECRET";
$text = "EYES ON LONDON Electric from Singapore Raffles Place";
$args = array();
$args["documentType"] = urlencode("text/plain");
$args["documentContent"] = urlencode($text);
$args["outputType"] = "json";
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"PUT", $url, $args);
$request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array($request->to_header());//.',Content-Length: '.strlen($text));
//$headers = array($request->to_header().',Content-Length="'.strlen($text).'"');
//$headers = array($request->to_header().',Content-Length: 277');
print_r($headers);
//print_r($headers.',Content-Length: '.strlen($text));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request->to_postdata());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n\n\n\n";
var_dump($rsp);
//print_r($rsp);
?>
```

Currently, this new code returns a

> {"bossresponse":{"responsecode":"500","reason":"non 200 status code
>   from backend: 415"}

error.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the error message ? please copy-paste here the error message you get.

Comment: Hi good day, the error message is: No Content Length

Description: Could not process this request because there was no Content-Length specified.

Comment: is the information enough ?

Comment: If you're getting headers from $request->to_header() then maybe you just need to save it, append the content length header to it and use it with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

Comment: @DjangoRocks Since you're making a GET request, the length of its body is 0. So the content length in your case should not be the length of the `$text`, but exactly 0. And also you should combine headers from OAuth and this particular `Content-Length` header together. So just edit your `$headers` definition as the following: `$headers = array($request->to_header(), 'Content-Length: 0');`. I don't have auth tokens for Yahoo, but if i send your request without my modification - i get the same error, but if with it - just `Please provide valid credentials`. so i expect it should work properly.

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode apologies i'm not a php CURL expert. How would the code look like ?

Comment: @user2655603 i'm making a POST request, not a GET request for your information.

Comment: @user2655603 i've tested out with your code sample, but I also got a `Please provide valid credentials` error despite using the correct credentials.

Comment: @DjangoRocks Sorry, my fault. I'll recheck the length with POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You send no POST data, hence no Content-Length being sent. To make a correct curl request you need to specify which data you like to send. In your case it is likely to be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request->to_postdata());
```

**IF** it should be a POST request. The [PlaceSpotter docs](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/placespotter_webservice.html) reads:

> The PlaceSpotter Web service supports only the HTTP PUT method. Other HTTP methods are not supported.

So I assume it should be PUT method instead:

```
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"PUT", $url,$args);
....
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```

**EDIT for 415 response code**

It may be an issue with double `urlencode`ing.

Try to set arguments as unencoded text:

```
$args["documentType"] = "text/plain";
$args["documentContent"] = $text;
```

Comment: Hi good day, I've tried to use PUT as per your code sample, but I still receive the `No Content Length Description: Could not process this request because there was no Content-Length specified.` error.

Comment: @DjangoRocks, `PUT` request still requires some data to send. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` still apply for `PUT` method.

Comment: Hi there, I've updated my code. But i'm now receiving `{"bossresponse":{"responsecode":"500","reason":"non 200 status code from backend: 415"}` error. is my code wrong ? Cheers.

Comment: Apparently their backend do not support requested media type. The Content-Length issue has been resolved from your side. The "415" error is the PlaceSpotter problem, which means your request was accepted by frontend API and successfully passed through.

Comment: wow geez. ok now this is weird. i assume the next step will be to contact Yahoo for support ?

Comment: @DjangoRocks, I have updated the answer regarding '415' response. First thing to do is to confirm you face the same problem with unencoded values for `documentType` and `documentContent`. If it is still the case, than yes, it makes sense to contact BOSS support team.

Comment: hi there, i think u nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

As per [RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) `Content-Type` header indicates the size of the entity-body without headers. So if you would like to make POST requests without entity-body you should specify `Content-Length: 0`. Give this a try.